# How to make my pen tool lock onto a guide

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool, guides

I am trying to create some vectored graphics on photoshop and I am having issues finding how to get my pen tool to lock onto a guide. I have a picture here showing what I am looking at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKCzR.jpg . I am hoping that there is a key I can press that allows photoshop to help me guide my pen tool to the guides I have made. Please let me know if there is a way to do this or if more clarification is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Snap**.

Turn on **Snap** from VIEW menu

Under **Snap** button in VIEW menu, you can see **Snap To**. From Snap to sub-menus select **Guides**.